# how to make dropdown selected when running dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html

my html code.

```
<input type="button" onClick="show($row['empDesignation']?>');" value="update"/>
```

so when i click on update button m passing the value to javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function show(desig){
    document.getElementById("designation").value=desig;
    }
    </script>
```

so i want the value which is passed to javacript to be listed first in the dropdown list

php code

```
<select id="designation" name="designation"> 
     <? while($role=mysql_fetch_array($sql_role)){    ?>
         <option value="<?=$role['id']?>"><?=$role['id']?></option>
    <? } ?></select>
```

Comment: <option selected value = ... will make that option selected or do you want it physically moved to the top?

Comment: Is that a copy of your HTML code? You are missing an opening `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="<?php echo $role['id']?>"><?php echo  $role['id']?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like following algorithm;

Get your entire select options and put it in to array
Remove all options from selectbox
Put first option that you get from `show` function
Fill rest of the item from array to selectbox.

You can see an example below;

```
  function show(desig) {
    var arr = [];
    var list = document.getElementById("designation");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.options.length; i++) {
    arr.push(list.options[i]);
    } 

    // Delete all options from selectbox
    list.options.length = 0;

    // create first option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = desig;
    opt.value = desig;
    list.appendChild(opt);


    for (var j in arr) {
    if (arr[j].value !== desig) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = arr[j].text;
    opt.value = arr[j].value;
    list.appendChild(opt);
    }
    }
}
```

You can see working demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/rZmgY/1/**